# TypeScript module namespacing in multiple files

Tags: typescript

I am trying to mimic a feature of C# in Typescript.

Let say I have this folder structure

```
App.ts
Models/
    Person.ts
    Message.ts
```

I then in `App.ts` want this:

```
module MyAppNamespace {
    export class ChatApp {
        User: Models.Person;
        constructor () => {
            this.User = new Models.Person("John");
            this.User.Message = new Models.Message("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. I think what you want to do is define a module that extends over several source files. To achieve this, you need to use an **internal** module as follows:

**Models/Person.ts**

```
module Model {

  export class Person {
      name: string;
      Message : Message;
      constructor(name: string) {
          this.name = name;
      }   
  }
}
```

**Models/Message.ts**

```
module Model {
   export class Message {
       message: string;
       constructor(message: string) {
          this.message = message;
       }   
   }
}
```

**App.ts**

```
///<reference path='Models/Person.ts'/>
///<reference path='Models/Message.ts'/>
module MyAppNamespace {
    export class ChatApp {
        User: Model.Person;
        constructor () => {
            this.User = new Model.Person("John");
            this.User.Message = new Model.Message("Hello World");
        }   
    }   
}
```

If you compile this with

```
tsc App.ts
```

then everything should work. Notice how module `outer` is declared in two source files. Since this is an **internal** module, we have to tell the compiler to put them into our scope by adding `///<reference path='foo.ts'/>` statements.

Comment: Works good in Visual studio too. Would it be possible to only have to import one of these files? In VS you normally use /// <reference path="_allRefs.js"/>. Would this be possible? E.g: <reference path="AllModels.ts"/>?

Comment: For future reference, this is possible. So you could create one file "allModels.ts" that contains the /// refs.

Comment: why store Person and Message in separate files? Could I have a Model.ts file with just the class definitions without being wrapped in a module? If so how would I import these definitions in App.ts..

Comment: UPDATE: Typescript 0.9.5 now have support for _referenes.ts (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx)

Comment: Since Typescript 1.5 "internal modules" are now "namespaces". In this example `module Model` should now be `namespace Model`.