# Require.js text plugin functionality for TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am building a Backbone app in TypeScript and I would like to put my templates in separate .html files (for syntax etc). I don't use Require.js now, how can I load text files then. I guess I have to write a function for that, but is there something already available in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the typescript compiler you can only compile Typescript files. Keeping your code in `html` files won't allow you to compile code.

If you want to load code from other Typescript files, the compiler currently supports `commonjs` and `amd` style imports of modules. You can tell the compiler which type of model to use by specifying `tsc --module commonjs` or `tsc --module amd`.

Typescript supports two different kinds of modules, namely `external` and `internal` modules. Depending on what type of module you use, importing it works differently. Take a look at section 9 of the language specification and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841557/whats-the-difference-between-internal-and-external-modules-in-typescript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845810/typescript-module-namespacing-in-multiple-files/12846385#12846385) answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [requirejs plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text) for loading non-code dependencies, in this case, some templates stored in separate html files.

[requirejs/text on github](https://github.com/requirejs/text/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score -1):

Someone wrote something similar at https://github.com/iammerrick/require-ts, though you will probably need to adapt it for your needs.