# Typescript : Import Module

Tags: module, typescript

I am trying to understand how to organize my code with Typescript modules.
Here is my following architecture:

`~
  src
    app
      SubModule1 (folder)
        Class1.ts
    components
      Component1.ts (require to create class 1)
    MainModule.ts`

// Class1.ts

```
module MainModule.SubModule1 {
    export class Class1 {
        // some code
    }
}
```

// Component1.ts

```
import MainModule = require("MainModule");
export class {
    constructor() { var test = new MainModule.SubModule1.Class1; }
}
```

// MainModule.ts

```
module MainModule {
    export var config = "config";
}

export = MainModule;
```

The Component1 class find the MainModule fine, but I cannot access the SubModule1 class.
Could someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: By the way I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845810/typescript-module-namespacing-in-multiple-files but I could not make it work.

Comment: internal vs. external modules https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that you need to import it too, but the long answer is that you should drop the `module` declarations when using external modules...

// Class1.ts

```
export class Class1 {
    // some code
}
```

// Component1.ts

```
import MainModule = require("../MainModule");
import SubModule = require("../app/SubModule1/Class1");

export class {
    constructor() {
        var test = new SubModule.Class1();
    }
}
```

// MainModule.ts

```
export var config = "config";
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, so I tried to follow your code but in component1.ts, the import of the second file I have the following error : Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type

Comment: Also, why should I not specify the name of the modules by myself, in order to make the code discoverable?

Comment: @user2465083 because each file is a module