# TypeScript module namespacing while preserving multiple files after compile

Tags: node.js, typescript

I would like to take advantage of TypeScript's namespace/module features while preserving a multi-file output (each .ts file is compiled to a separate .js file.)

My desired organization and syntax is virtually the same as this QA: [TypeScript module namespacing in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845810/typescript-module-namespacing-in-multiple-files).

However, rather than having TS compile all the files into one, I'm looking for a way to preserve the original file structure and have the compiler inject the necessary `require()` statements needed to make it work in Node.

e.g.

**app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./model/animal.ts" />
var myAnimal = new MyNamespace.Model.Animal();
```

would compile to

**app.js**

```
var MyNamespace = { Model: { Animal: require('./model/animal') } };
var myAnimal = new MyNamespace.Model.Animal()
```

or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What steve said. Use external modules. Just fixing up the syntax:

```
import AnimalModel = require("./model/animal");
var myAnimal = new AnimalModel.Animal();
```

Basically same as `var/require` combo except that you use `import` to tell typescript to look for a `.ts` file and do its type inference.

Also to compile for Node use the `--module commonjs` module flag.

```
tsc --module commonjs app.ts
```

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Is it possible to use namespace-style syntax when importing external modules? i.e. `import RB.Model.Animal = require('./model/animal');`

Comment: Well, after some research it appears not so much. I made an issue on TypeScript Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/332

Answer (score 0):

To take advantage of external modules (which were built for exactly this purpose), use the following:

```
import AnimalModel = "./model/animal.ts";
var myAnimal = new AnimalModel .Animal();
```

You don't need to use the `module` keyword in the `animal.ts` file.

You also need to pass the appropriate compiler module mode - for AMD (RequireJS) you pass `--module amd`...

```
tsc --module amd app.ts
```